# Modelandview object coming as blank

Tags: spring

I am completely new to spring mvc I have been trying to work on Hello world example below given are the files that I am using 
When I am running this code ${message} in hello.jsp keeps on coming as blank

```
package com.tutorialspoint;  

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  

@Controller  
public class HelloWorldController {  

  @RequestMapping("/hello")  
     public ModelAndView helloWorld() {  

         String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";  
         return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);  
     }  
}
```

JSP files named as hello.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Below file is spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

 <context:component-scan base-package="javaguys.tutorials.spring" />  
 <bean id="viewResolver"  
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">  

  <property name="viewClass"  
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />  
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  

 </bean>  
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

your controller is located in the package `com.tutorialspoint;` and your component-scan dosn't scan this package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="javaguys.tutorials.spring" />
```

add another componen-scan like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />
```

or define your controller's bean manually.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not very up-to-date and good example to start learning Spring.

@SpringBootApplication contains @ComponentScan and can do it automatically and adds @EnableSpringMVC and config annotations, also .jsp are not used anymore besides some old huge legacy projects, so it would be better to learn React, Angular as frontend side.

Check out the spring.io, baeldung, mkyong and good luck with your studies!

[Official tutorials](http://spring.io)

[Spring Hello World](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/)